# ArrayindexOutOfBounds Exception strange tried to refactor many times Kotlin issue

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The app has a bottomnavigation of two tabs one for tasks and one for notes.

I get no errror on the start as it starts by loding the tasks. but when I press the notes tab it crashes.

[image: logcat on crash when clicking the notes app]

have subtracted 1 from the position of the masterlist as I have added a button to the top (1st position in the array) thinking this would correct it.

BaseRecyclerAdapter class

```
abstract class BaseRecyclerAdapter<T>(
    protected val masterList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = masterList.size + 1

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is TaskAdapter.AddButtonViewHolder) {
            holder.onBind(Unit)
        } else {
            (holder as BaseViewHolder<T>).onBind(masterList[position - 1])
        }
    }


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        if (position == 0) {
            TYPE_ADD_BUTTON
        } else {
            TYPE_INFO
        }

    abstract class BaseViewHolder<E>(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        abstract fun onBind(data: E)
    }

    abstract class AddButtonViewHolder(view: View) : BaseViewHolder<Unit>(view)

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_ADD_BUTTON = 0
        const val TYPE_INFO = 1
    }
}
```

NotesAdapter

```
class NoteAdapter(notesList: MutableList<Note> = mutableListOf()) : BaseRecyclerAdapter<Note>(notesList) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =

        if(viewType == TYPE_ADD_BUTTON){
            AddButtonViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_add_button, parent, false))
        } else {
            NoteViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_note, parent, false))

        }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        if(position == 0){
            TYPE_ADD_BUTTON
        }else {
            TYPE_INFO
        }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = masterList.size + 1


    class NoteViewHolder(view: View) :BaseViewHolder<Note>(view){

        override fun onBind(data: Note) {
            (view as NoteView).initView(data)
        }
    }

    class AddButtonViewHolder(view: View): BaseRecyclerAdapter.AddButtonViewHolder(view){
        override fun onBind(data: Unit) {
            view.buttonText.text = view.context.getText(R.string.add_button_note)
        }

    }
}
```

NoteListFragment

```
class NotesListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerViewNote.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val adapter = NoteAdapter(mutableListOf(
            Note("Ben Mohammad", null),
            Note("Joesph and and Maria", null)
        ))
        recyclerViewNote.adapter = adapter
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstance() = NotesListFragment()
    }

}
```

NoteView

```
class NoteView @JvmOverloads constructor (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 1) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){

    fun initView(note: Note){
        description.text = note.description
  }
}
```

I've used Custom views nested That is what I'm trying to do....obviously trying to keep it very OOP style getting stuck with it...

```
class TaskAdapter(
    tasksList: MutableList<Task> = mutableListOf()
) : BaseRecyclerAdapter<Task>(tasksList) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =

        if (viewType == TYPE_INFO) {
            TaskViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_task, parent, false))
        } else {
            AddButtonViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_add_button, parent, false))
        }

    class TaskViewHolder(view: View) : BaseViewHolder<Task>(view) {

        override fun onBind(data: Task) {
            (view as TaskView).initView(data)

        }
    }


    class AddButtonViewHolder(view: View) : BaseRecyclerAdapter.AddButtonViewHolder(view) {
        override fun onBind(data: Unit) {
            view.buttonText.text = view.context.getText(R.string.add_button_task)
        }

    }


}
```

TasksListfragment

```
class TasksListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val adapter = TaskAdapter(
            mutableListOf(
                Task(
                    "Testing one!!",
                    mutableListOf(
                        Todo("Test 1!!"),
                        Todo("Test 2!!", true)


                    )
                ),
                Task("Testing two!!")
            )
        )
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    companion object {


        fun newInstance() = TasksListFragment()
    }

}
```

TaskView

```
class TaskView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 1) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {


    lateinit var task: Task

    fun initView(task: Task) {
        this.task = task

        titleView.text = task.title
        task.todos.forEach {

                todo ->
            val todoView =
                (LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_todo, todoContainer, false) as TodoView).apply {
                    initView(todo) {
                        if (isTaskcomplete()) {
                            createstrikeThrough()
                        } else {
                            removeStrikeThrough()
                        }

                    }
                }


            todoContainer.addView(todoView)

        }
    }

    fun isTaskcomplete(): Boolean = task.todos.filter { !it.isComplete }.isEmpty()

    private fun createstrikeThrough() {
        titleView.apply {
            paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }


    }

    private fun removeStrikeThrough() {
        titleView.apply {
            paintFlags = paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }

    }
}
```

For further classes, [all code is pushed to GitHub](https://github.com/BenMohammad/Notes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Please read [mcve] with emphasis on the **minimal** part. People aren't very willing to trawl through hundreds of lines of someone else's code distributed over various files to debug it. Make us volunteers happy and more willing to help you by trying to write the smallest code necessary to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
> if (holder is TaskAdapter.AddButtonViewHolder) { // <--- problematic line
>     holder.onBind(Unit)
> } else {
>     (holder as BaseViewHolder<T>).onBind(masterList[position - 1])
> }
> ```

You have two different subclasses of `BaseRecyclerAdapter`: your `TaskAdapter` and your `NotesAdapter`. When this is called for position `0` for your `NotesAdapter`, the `if (holder is ...)` check will fail, because the type is `NotesAdapter.AddButtonViewHolder`.

This will cause execution to fall into the `else` case, and your `masterList[position - 1]` logic will wind up querying for index `-1`.

To work around this, use the view type instead of checking the subclass with `is`. The base `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class has a `getItemViewType()` method that will return to you whatever you returned from your adapter. Since the view type logic is defined in your base adapter class, this will be the same regardless of which concrete implementation type is being used.

```
if (holder.itemViewType == TYPE_ADD_BUTTON) {
    (holder as AddButtonViewHolder).onBind(Unit)
} else {
    (holder as BaseViewHolder<T>).onBind(masterList[position - 1])
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i've taken not ethat the question should be better. thanks again